# Android button xml issue

Tags: android, xml

I'm getting an error, Binary XML file line #46: Error inflating class, my Button xml starts on this line and commenting it out stops the crash.

I also found an error saying java.lang.OutOfMemoryError, my image is only 48kb.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnTwitter"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/twitter_btn"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/emergency_btn_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/emergency_btn_margin"/>
```

The following is my twitter_btn.xml file that is used as the button background:

```
<item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <item>
            <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:shape="oval">
                <padding android:top="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:bottom="3dp" android:left="3dp" />
                <solid android:color="#20CCCCCC" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:shape="oval">
                <padding android:top="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:bottom="3dp" android:left="3dp" />
                <solid android:color="#30CCCCCC" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:shape="oval">
                <padding android:top="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:bottom="3dp" android:left="3dp" />
                <solid android:color="#50CCCCCC" />
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item>
            <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="@color/blue"/>
                <padding
                    android:bottom="1dp"
                    android:left="1dp"
                    android:right="1dp"
                    android:top="1dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <bitmap
                android:src="@drawable/twitter" />
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>

<item>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
            <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:shape="oval">
                <padding android:top="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:bottom="3dp" android:left="3dp" />
                <solid android:color="#20CCCCCC" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:shape="oval">
                <padding android:top="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:bottom="3dp" android:left="3dp" />
                <solid android:color="#30CCCCCC" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:shape="oval">
                <padding android:top="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:bottom="3dp" android:left="3dp" />
                <solid android:color="#50CCCCCC" />
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item>
            <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
                <padding
                    android:bottom="1dp"
                    android:left="1dp"
                    android:right="1dp"
                    android:top="1dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <bitmap
                android:src="@drawable/twitter" />
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
```

So after getting this issue I moved the setting of the background to code and not xml, now I only get the OutOfMemory exception, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The issue had to do with the image I was using in the xml file, once I started using another image everything worked